# Use array in mysql query java

Tags: java, mysql

I have two questions for java mysql

First, I have an array containing either 1 or 0.

If i want do to an if statement how can i then check if opt[0] = 1?
is it like:

```
if (options[0] == 1
{
sqlBuilder.append("AND a.value1 = val[1]")
}
```

next question.
I have another array containing different values, how can i use them in a mysql query.

Right now i got

```
StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder()
.append("SELECT * ")
.append("FROM `table1` a ")
.append("CROSS JOIN `table2` b ")
.append("CROSS JOIN ` table3` c ")
.append("CROSS JOIN `table4` d")
.append("WHERE c.`id` =" . val[0] );
```

So i need c.id = val[0]

Comment: For the first question; yes that looks fine aside from the missing `)` after the `==1`. Assuming that `options[]` is an `int[]`.

Comment: @Mister: No, he is missing a closing parenthesis, lol. Same for the second example, just replace `.` by `+` and you are fine.

Comment: true i miss a closing. But when i wrte if (options[0] == 1) i get the error operand strings and int.. options is a string[]

Comment: Shouldn't `"AND a.value1 = val[1]"` actually be `"AND a.value1 = '" + val[1] + "'"`? And btw, this is quite vulnerable to SQL injection so please use `PreparedStatement`s instead.

Comment: @KlausJoeChristiansen: See my answer, you cannot compare `int` with `String`; this is neither PHP nor Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, i will look into preparedstatements!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your code is correct.

The thing that is incorrect is your Java syntax. Are you coming from PHP? Strings are concatenated with `+` in Java, so your last line should be

```
.append("WHERE c.`id` =" + val[0] );
```

In addition, you seem to mess up types; if your `option` array is a `String[]` then you need to compare it with strings or cast the value to `int`, so your first if must look like this:

```
if("1".equals(options[0]))
```

or

```
if(Integer.parseInt(options[0]) == 1)
```

**Note:**

As Thomas correctly states in his comment, you should consider using [PreparedStatments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of your hardcoded statements to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yes i am coming from PHP. I will definetly look into prepared statements. Thanks